# How to improve this .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I created the following .htaccess file and I am wondering if it could be improved:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site$ ./site/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ ./main/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./404.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

I want to redirect visitors which enter www.domain.com/site/ to www.domain.com/main/ and all other requests to www.domain.com/404.php?url=... This works, except when the user doesn't enter a trailing slash (www.domain.com/site).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with a /? like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^site$ ./site/? [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ ./main/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/en [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./404.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first rule, you rewrite `site` to `site/` and then rewrite `site/` to `main/`. I would rather do it in one step, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^site/?$ ./main/ [L,NC]
```

The second rule would stay as it is.

---

With the current rules, you only redirect nonexisting paths to `404.php`. If this is what you want, everything is fine. If not, you should remove `!-f` and `!-d` conditions and add a condition to exclude `main` from being rewritten to `404`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/main/ [NC]
```

Even though the substitution `./404.php` is valid, I would write it as

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404.php?url=$1 [L,NC]
```